# Using maven-plugins annotations outside of maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm trying to transfer the functionality of a maven plugin into a standalone java commandline application. The maven plugin is using the [maven plugin annotations](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/) e.g. the `@Component` annotation.

```
@Mojo( name = "customGoal" )
public class CustomMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Component( hint = "customHint" )
    private MyCustomComponent cmp;

    public vodi execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        // Funcionality of my custom maven plugin
    }
}
```

When the maven plugin starts, the annotated object `cmp` is injected via maven. The class `MyCustomComponent` is also using the maven plugin annotations e.g. `@Requirement`:

```
@Component(role = MyCustomComponentInterface.class, hint = "customHint")
public class MyCustomComponent implements MyCustomComponentInterface {

    @Requirement
    private AnyRequiredObject obj;

    @Requirement
    privater OtherRequiredObject obj2;

    // Funcionality
}
```

How can I achieve the same behaviour in a standalone java application? Is there a solution for such a use case?

Comment: First what kind of functionality? The @Component/@Requirement annotations are things related to dependency injection framework in Maven..you can use in a stand alone app Google Guice for example...

Comment: Functionality like doing stuff with maven repositories etc... Do you have any example with Google Guice